# Getting error when I call class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift. I have a simple class in swift

```
class ListItem: NSObject {
let itemName: String
var completed: Bool

init(itemName: String, completed: Bool = false)
{
self.itemName = itemName
self.completed = completed
}
}
```

When I refer to this class in my TableViewController, I get the following error:
"Instance member itemName cannot be used on type ListItem".

My TableViewController code (cellForRowAtIndexPath method) is shown below.

```
    let tempCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("triggerCell")! as UITableViewCell
    let listItem = listItems[indexPath.row]

    // Downcast from UILabel? to UILabel
    let cell = tempCell.textLabel as UILabel!


    cell.text = ListItem.itemName

    if (ListItem.completed)
    {
        tempCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;
    }
    else
    {
        tempCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None;
    }

    return tempCell
}
```

I'm probably making a basic error, but I can't seem to identify where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the class instead of your instance. Try this:

```
cell.text = listItem.itemName

if (listItem.completed)
etc...
```

EDIT: Updating the creation of `listItems`.

```
let listItems = [ListItem("Viruses"), ListItem("Changes in weather"), etc...]
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried that, but get error "Value of type 'String' has no member 'itemName'"

Comment: What is the type of the listItems array? [String] or [ListItem]?

Comment: String 
let listItems = ["Viruses", "Changes in weather", "House dust mites", "Animal dander", "Foods", "Exercise", "Upset, distress and emotions", "Smoke - cigarettes and fires"]

Comment: Yeah, that's an array of Strings. You need to create ListItem objects and put those in an array. I can update my answer to include that.